# difference of days between unix timestamps in r

Tags: r, unix, timestamp

I have two columns of Unix timestamps as below and my code doesn't work here. Just wondering what is the right way calculate the difference of days(Measure_Time$duration) between these two timestamp?
Appreciate your help!

```
  Measure_Time<- data.frame(start=c("2015-10-23T21:15:07Z ","2012-01-04T06:21:10Z "), end=c("2016-03-19T22:46:09Z ","2016-03-19T21:21:28Z "))

 Measure_Time$duration<- as.Date(as.character(Measure_Time $end), format="%Y/%m/%d/%h/%m/%s")-
              as.Date(as.character(Measure_Time $ start), format="%Y/%m/%d/%h/%m/%s")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the times to unix timestamps and calculate the day difference from there;

```
Measure_Time$duration <- (as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Measure_Time$end)) -
                          as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Measure_Time$start)))/86400
```

Comment: You can also use `difftime` to control the units..`difftime(as.POSIXct(Measure_Time$end),
                          as.POSIXct(Measure_Time$start), units="days")`